# android file download is not working in pie version

Tags: java, android

```
 public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String str_id, str_docName;
        public DownloadFile(String id, String docName) {
            str_id = id;
            str_docName = docName;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Downloading..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url1 = "http://pap.india.com/API/s3_file_download?gid=" + str_id + "&filename=" + str_docName + "&type=icfo";

            downloadFile(url1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void downloadFile(String urlString) {
        dManager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        if (!urlString.equals("")) {
            try {
                String fileName = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(urlString));
                request.setDescription("Download" + fileName + " from "
                        + urlString);
                request.setTitle("DownloadManager" + file_name);
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                final File dir = new File(Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory(), "sample");
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/sample/" + fileName));

//                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "sample.pdf");

                long did = dManager.enqueue(request);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

I am implementing the download option for downloading uploaded files in my app.The issue is i am able to download files in all mobile versions except pie version.The file is not downloading when i try to download in pie mobile version.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to help you without knowing the exact exception / error you are getting, but looking at your URL I can guess the issue is **http**.

Starting with API level 28 - Android 9 PIE , all web requests are required to be secure by default.
If you try to access URL that does not start with **https** without specifically whitelisting it in your manifest, you will get an error.

[Read here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CleartextTrafficPermitted) how to whitelist domains or disable this feature completely.

Also, I recommend you go over the list of major changes for Android Pie [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28).